# Find diagram for understanding pyqgis

Tags: pyqt, python-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

In orther to undestand the api of pyqgis, i'd like to konw where can i find a diagram of pyqgis api ?

Comment: Have you tried its documentation?

Comment: @PolyGeo  okey good, thank you. When i click on a class i saw it.